# Spock given, when, then, where interaction check does not work

Tags: bdd, spock

I have the following spock test

```
def "setXandSave saves the parcel with the chosen xValue"() {
    given:
    jpaRepository.findOne(parcelId) >> parcel

    when:
    repository.setXandSave(parcelId, xValue)

    then:
    1 * parcel.setX(xValue)
    1 * jpaRepository.save(parcel)

    where:
    parcelId | parcel                   | xValue
    10L      | Mock(ParcelEntity.class) | "a"
    20L      | Mock(ParcelEntity.class) | "B"
}
```

I get an error "Too few invocations for:.." for the line `1 * parcel.setX(xValue)`.

Am I doing something incorrectly or is this a limitation of Spock? I debugged the `setXandSave` method while running the test and `setX` is indeed called.
But spock says

```
Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

Any help regarding how to debug the problem is also appreciated.

Comment: If I remember well you would have to stub `jpaRepository.findOne(parcelId) >> parcel` in `then:` block.

Comment: Could you share some more code, e.g. the creation of repository and the `setXandSave` method. Furhtermore, why are you creating the mock in the where block and not in the given block?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason to have `where` block here in your case. The second column has the duplication and can be extracted from table. Also from test perspective there no difference between input 10/'a' and '20'/'B' pairs. So, we can simplify your test to:

```
def "setXandSave saves the parcel with the chosen xValue"() {
    given:
    def parcelId = 10L
    def xValue = 'a'

    and:
    def parcel = Mock(ParcelEntity)
    jpaRepository.findOne(parcelId) >> parcel

    when:
    repository.setXandSave(parcelId, xValue)

    then:
    1 * parcel.setX(xValue)
    1 * jpaRepository.save(parcel)
}
```